# Iterating over form elements htmlunit

Tags: java, forms, element, htmlunit

Do you know if htmlunit supports form iteration where the form elements are returned. 
I can get to specific  element by using the getInputByName, or even using the value if the element name doesn't exist. But how about getting all the elements of a specific form in list for example. is that possible or would i need to parse the form myself

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the docs :

```
XPath is the suggested way for more complex searches, a brief tutorial can be found in W3Schools

@Test
public void xpath() throws Exception {
    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net");

    //get list of all divs
    final List<?> divs = page.getByXPath("//div");

    //get div which has a 'name' attribute of 'John'
    final HtmlDivision div = (HtmlDivision) page.getByXPath("//div[@name='John']").get(0);

    webClient.closeAllWindows();
}
```

SO: No, its is not possiable, you can use XPath (A java library for parsing xml(html is xml)) to get your desired affect.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate in multiple ways for example selecting rows and iterating on them

```
    HtmlTable table = (HtmlTable) filings_page.getByXPath(
            "//table[@class='GDOGFYVLF']").get(0);
    java.util.List<HtmlTableRow> table_rows = table.getRows();
    for (int i = 1; i < table.getRows().size(); i++) {
      //your logic
    }
```